# Laravel 4 auth role based page access

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

What is best way to have page access restricted to authentication role / permit? I was thinking using `Auth::user()->role` for detection which will be put into every route section. So, is there any better way or best practice for doing this in Laravel 4?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like this (use a filter for role checking)

```
Route::filter('role', function()
{
    return Auth::user()->role;
});
```

Then in your routes, you can use this (`role`) filter like

```
Route::get('protectedPage1', array('before'=>'role', function($role) {
    if($role != 'admin') {
        return Redirect::to('home');
    }
}));

Route::get('protectedPage2', array('before'=>'role', function($role) {
    if($role != 'admin') {
        return Redirect::to('home');
    }
}));
```

**Update:**

```
Route::filter('role', function()
{
    if(Auth::user()->role != 'admin') {
        return Redirect::to('home');
    }
});

Route::get('protectedPage1', array('before'=>'role', function() {
    // do your job
}));
```

Comment: Hey, your example seems to be didn't work. As soon as the filter return an value, it display the returned data on the webpage and stop processing the rest of the code.